# Angular - How to validate multiple fields loaded dynamically (in various components)

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, typescript

I am creating classifieds site on Angular.
Main component of the route consist from:

- static fields (name, email, phone, location, etc.) described in it's template
- component loaded dynamically, with it's own template (separate fields)

I use Reactive Forms Model to validate static fields in main component.
And if field is valid I write it's value to the service property.

How can I validate fields that loaded with dynamic component and gather data from main and dynamic component to one object/array?

Answer (score 0):

The form that is being loaded dynamically can built using the same method used to build dynamic forms. I would build the dynamic form grammatically using reactive forms.

[Building Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html)

From there if there is a parent child relationship between the components you could use Viewchild to get the validation state/values of the dynamically rendered form.

Otherwise you can always use a service to store and share information between components including the validation state of the form(s).